# TextBox Enter Key Result in New Line

Tags: .net, wpf, textbox

TextBox and I want an enter key to insert a CR LF.  Got this far:

`<TextBox Height="auto" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" TextWrapping="Wrap"/`>

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add`AcceptReturn` attribute

```
<TextBox Height="auto" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742157.aspx

Comment: Wow  Accepted the answer but for a an additional +1 how could I concatenate multiple adjacent CR LF to a single.  I have to wait 9 minutes to accept.